# How to configure TLS for Netty in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, reactor-netty

My microservices are using the latest releases of Spring Boot, Spring WebFlux (Undertow), Spring Data MongoDB, Spring Cloud Netflix, and Kotlin...

Now I've setup a demo project to use the new functional interface instead of the annotations in Spring WebFlux. Using Netty with HTTP works fine. However, I cannot find any information how to configure Netty with TLS resp. HTTPS. Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, configuration of TLS with Netty hasn't been implemented. The work is being tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9431).